# will ios 6.1.2 work with ubuntu 12.10?

Tags: 12.10, iphone, gnome-session, ios

I am slowly adopting Ubuntu as my primary OS, and Open Source software for my applications. Libre Office is fine for me, GIMP will take a steep learning curve to replace Photoshop, Tax Act has an online version that imports last year's Win Desptop tax filing, ThunderBird is great, Chromium easily replaces Chrome, there are others with which I've had marginal success.  I am pretty stumped by my iphone, iCloud synch for pictures, and transfering music. I'm keeping my Win 7 installation in tact for just a few applications while I learn and adopt to Linux / Ubuntu.

Is there a relatively straight forward method for my iPhone 4 (ios 6.1.2) to work with my desktop running Ubuntu 12.10 - gnome session fallback?

Comment: I did the steps above. Didn't work for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Functionality is very limited for iPhone users on Ubuntu, But there are some workarounds.

For your images I would suggest syncing them with dropbox, you can set your phone up to do this automagically, (when the app is open), thus automagically syncing them to your computer.

**For Music:** This directions are for the iPod but I imagine the steps will be the same for iPhone.

Connect the iPod to your computer using the iPod's USB cable. It may take a few seconds for the computer to recognize the iPod. Note than Ubuntu distributions prior to 10.04 do not recognize the iPod as an MP3 player, but rather, as a storage device.

2
Ubuntu automatically loads the Music Player application.

3
Click on "Music" in the Music Player window. Select "Import File" from the drop-down menu to import music into your library.

4
Click the music on your computer that you want to add to your iPod and drag it to the iPod’s icon. This icon has your iPod’s name on it under the Devices heading. Each time you drag and drop music on the icon, your iPod will update.

5
Close out of Music Player when you are finished loading music on your iPod. Right-click the iPod icon on your desktop and click "Eject." Wait for Ubuntu to tell you that the iPod has been disconnected. Unplug the iPod from the computer and enjoy your music.

Read more: How to Put Music on Your iPod Using Ubuntu | eHow.com http://www.ehow.com/how_2113536_put-music-ipod-using-ubuntu.html#ixzz2NL0wOiAR

Comment: This will definitely not work with a new iPhone.

Answer (score 0):

As listed in the [libimobiledevice website](http://www.libimobiledevice.org/) , functionality with iOS devices is limited and varies by feature. In particular, Music synchronization **will not work** with an up-to-date iPhone. This has nothing to do with the particular desktop setup you have, but with the libraries used to sync with your iPhone.

Other things might or might not work (look at the table on the website for details).